# bad operant types for binary operators'||' first type: boolean, second type: int?

Tags: java

I have this bit of code where i have the user input a number from 1 to 100 and the they are told whether or not their number is a Prime number. I get this error on my else if statement where it says "bad operant types for binary operators'||' first type: boolean, second type: int."

ive tried putting brackets arrounf the whole set of numbers and around each number individually but it just wont work. Any thoughts?

```
//setting up if statements to check if the user inputed number is a prime or not
        if(bytPrimeOrNot < 2)
        {
            bolPrime = false;
        }
        else if(bytPrimeOrNot == 2||3||5||7||11||13||17||19||23||29||31||37||41||43||47||53||59||61||67||71||73||79||83||89||97)
        {
            
          bolPrime = true;
        }
        else
        {
           
            bolPrime = false;
        }
```

Comment: That's just not valid java syntax you are using. `bytPrimeOrNot == 2 || bytPrimeOrNot == 3` cannot be shortened to `bytPrimeOrNot == 2 || 3`

Comment: add your numbers to a list and check if the list contains the input number

Comment: You could use `Set.of(2,3,....).contains(bytPrimeOrNot)` (and you could create the set elsewhere if you're going to reuse it).

Comment: *Any thoughts?* - Since you have asked for general advice, when you are learning a new programming language, it is a bad idea to guess the syntax and semantics.  It is inefficient, and you are liable to write code with confusing compiler and runtime errors ... or that simply doesn't do what you expect it to.  Instead, find a decent tutorial or textbook that explains the syntax.  (And read it ...)

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening in your code is that it is comparing 'bytPrimeOrNot == 2' which is a boolean type with '3', which is an integer. This is why you are getting that error.

```
else if(bytPrimeOrNot > 1 || bytPrimeOrNot < 100) {
    bolPrime = true;
}
```

This is the appropriate way to use the '||' symbol in a conditional statement. Hopefully, this solves your problem.